# JS: Can i use 'then' after I'm pushing a filtered array into another array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called `products`.  I have another array called `otherProds`.  I am running a function that filters `otherProds` and then using the spread syntax to push that array into `products` array. How can I do something ONLY after this completes?  I tried using `then` and it's logging what I put in but it's also throwing an error `TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).push.apply(...).then is not a function`

My code:

`products.push(...this.filterInventory(otherProds)).then(console.log("do something after"));`

Answer (score 1):

"then" only works for promises. If "this.filterInventory(otherProds)" returns a promise, you can do "this.filterInventory(otherProds).then(result => products.push(...result));"

Answer (score 1):

`Array.push()` returns the count of the array which is updated. So the output of the `push` function will be numeric value which will not have any function like `then` which will be available only in `Promise`.
Moreover, `push` is a synchronous function. So you can just place your `console.log` in the next line which will work as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to push the otherProds to products and do whatever you want you can do it like below.
    `products.push(...this.filterInventory(otherProds));`
    `console.log("do something");`

[Then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) function returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

No. `Array.push()` does not return object `Promise`.
And also `Array.push()` is not async functio , so even if you could, using `then(console.log())` and just `console.log()` on the next line will not have any difference